# .htaccess handling leading forward slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a project which I wish to place in a sub-directory of a web root directory.

So if I had:
/public_html as the web root directory

I want the project to live in:
/public_html/myproject

Now, the project will eventually live in the root folder, so I want to make as few code changes as possible, but during testing it must stay in the sub-directory.

The issue is with the following:

```
<img src="/images/image1.png" alt="" />
```

This works fine when the project is in the document root, because the leading forward-slash is doing it's job.

However, when the project is in the sub-directory, the / takes the relative path back to the web root folder.

How can I alter .htaccess to prevent this? I need the leading forward slash to reference the "/myproject" folder instead.

Any ideas on how it can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the apache module mod_rewrite enabled, you could add the following to your .htaccess file in the root folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /
RewriteRule   ^images(.*)  /myproject/images/$1
```

You can find more information on this here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks David - I've been messing around with rewrite all afternoon, and then your post has made me realise that the .htaccess file should be in root, and not in the sub-directory. It's all working now :)